# Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i(1-p)^{i-1}p=\frac{1-(1-p)^{n-1}\left(1+\left(n-1\right)p\right)}{p}$

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series

In the following [exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1597954) the following transition was made:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i\left(1-p\right)^{i-1}p=\frac{1-\left(1-p\right)^{n-1}\left(1+\left(n-1\right)p\right)}{p},$$
where $0<p<1$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

It would be great if you can explain it to me.

Comment: to add to @DonaldSplutterwit 's hint. You can use the partial sum for the geometric series and differentiate to obtain that.

Comment: Hint :
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} i x^i = \frac{1+nx^{n+2}-(n+1)x^{n+2}}{(1-x)^2}
\end{eqnarray*}
is easily proved by induction.

Comment: @mathma Yes. Differentiating a geometric series is probably the best method to derive the formula from scratch.

Comment: By the way, *Welcome to the site !* - For this kind of problems, it is always the same kind of tricks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following suggestions in the comment note first that:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^{i}=\frac{x^{n+1}-x}{x-1}
$$
Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ yields

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}ix^{i-1}=\frac{nx^{n+1}+1-x^{n}\left(n+1\right)}{\left(x-1\right)^{2}}$$

Substitute $x=1-p$ and multiplying both sides by $p$ yields
\begin{align*}
p\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i\left(1-p\right)^{i-1}
&=\frac{\left(n-1\right)\left(1-p\right)^{n}+1-\left(1-p\right)^{n-1}n}{\left(\left(1-p\right)-1\right)^{2}}\cdot p\\
&=\frac{n\left(1-p\right)^{n+1}+1-\left(1-p\right)^{n}\left(n+1\right)}{p}\\
&=\frac{1-\left(1-p\right)^{n-1}\left[\left(1-n\right)\left(1-p\right)+n\right]}{p}\\
&=\frac{1-\left(1-p\right)^{n-1}\left[1-p-n+np+n\right]}{p}\\
&=\frac{1-\left(1-p\right)^{n-1}\left[1+p\left(n-1\right)\right]}{p}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i\left(1-p\right)^{i-1}p=p\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i\left(1-p\right)^{i-1}=-p\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(1-p\right)^{i}\right)'$$