# An issue with a solution to a problem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, analysis, measure-theory

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1597954), If @ki3i is correct, then the graphs: [image: those graphs] should be the same (because both represent $\mathbb{E}(X)$) whenever $0<p<1$ (but they are not).

What do you think?

Comment: Please make titles informative; this title doesn't say *anything* about what the post is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\color{red}9}i\left(1-p\right)^{\left(i-1\right)}p+\color{blue}{10\left(1-p\right)^{9}}=\frac{1-\left(1-p\right)^{10}}{p}$$

Note the left hand side is different from the formula you use.